# White screen of death after an auto update of WordPress

Tags: fatal-error

My website - **www.In2BalanceKInesiology.com.au** had an WordPress auto update a few days ago and I have not been able to access it since - it is a white screen of death...

Comment: Enable your debugger in `wp-config.php` file and if any error is appear

Comment: I can access your site without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, enable debugging in WordPress by setting this in your **wp-config.php** file:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

After that you could also increase the memory allocated to PHP by setting this in your **wp-config.php** file:

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

More information about editing the **wp-config.php** file / WordPress configuration file, see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

For more information about debugging see below and/or this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

> ### Example wp-config.php for Debugging
>
> The following code, inserted in your wp-config.php file, will log all
>   errors, notices, and warnings to a file called debug.log in the
>   wp-content directory. It will also display the errors.
>
> ```
> // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
> define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
>
> // Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
> define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
>
> // The SAVEQUERIES definition saves the database queries to an array and that array can be displayed to help analyze those queries.  
> define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Steps to follow for solving  white screen of death issue are as follows:

1) Please Enable Debug Mode true in wp-config.php file using 
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
2) If any message does not appear in frontend or backend then deactivate all the plugins and try to activate it one by one and check it in frontend and backend. You can deactivate it using commenting the -- at the starting of folder name of plugin.
3) If any message does not appear by checking plugins comment all the themes same as plugins by renaming it -- at the starting of folder name of themes.
```